AMD Radeon HD 8570, active or not, trying to run Sober
Not a geek here. I need help. I am trying to run Sober on my 10 year old desktop for Roblox (for my son).

I searched online, found some info, and followed the instructions, but nothing worked.
https://linuxconfig.org/amd-radeon-ubuntu-20-04-driver-installation
https://wiki.debian.org/AtiHowTo#AMDGPU.2FVulkan_on_older_cards
    @hp-desktop:~$ sudo lshw -c video
  *-display                 
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Oland [Radeon HD 8570 / R5 430 OEM / R7 240/340 / Radeon 520 OEM]
       vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       logical name: /dev/fb0
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm pciexpress msi vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom fb
       configuration: depth=32 driver=radeon latency=0 resolution=1920,1080
       resources: irq:42 memory:c0000000-cfffffff memory:fea00000-
fea3ffff ioport:e000(size=256) memory:c0000-dffff


@hp-desktop:~$ lsmod | grep amd
amdgpu              17104896  0
amdxcp                 12288  1 amdgpu
drm_exec               12288  1 amdgpu
gpu_sched              61440  1 amdgpu
drm_buddy              20480  1 amdgpu
edac_mce_amd           28672  0
drm_suballoc_helper    16384  2 amdgpu,radeon
drm_ttm_helper         12288  2 amdgpu,radeon
ttm                   110592  3 amdgpu,radeon,drm_ttm_helper
drm_display_helper    237568  2 amdgpu,radeon
i2c_algo_bit           16384  2 amdgpu,radeon
video                  73728  2 amdgpu,radeon

@hp-desktop:~$ sudo dmesg | grep -i amdgpu
[   10.804578] [drm] amdgpu kernel modesetting enabled.
[   10.804825] amdgpu: Virtual CRAT table created for CPU
[   10.804855] amdgpu: Topology: Add CPU node

GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden
GRUB_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`( . /etc/os-release; echo ${NAME:-Ubuntu} ) 2>/dev/null || echo Ubuntu`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash radeon.cik_support=0 amdgpu.cik_support=1"

GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
#GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER=false
#GRUB_BADRAM="0x01234567,0xfefefefe,0x89abcdef,0xefefefef"
#GRUB_TERMINAL=console
#GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480
#GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_UUID=true
#GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY="true"
#GRUB_INIT_TUNE="480 440 1"

System info:
@hp-desktop:~$ uname
Linux
    
@hp-desktop:~$ uname -n
hp-desktop
    
@hp-desktop:~$ uname -v
#48-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Fri Sep 27 14:04:52 UTC 2024
    
@hp-desktop:~$ uname -r
6.8.0-48-generic
    
@hp-desktop:~$ uname -m
x86_64
    
@hp-desktop:~$ uname -a
Linux hp-desktop 6.8.0-48-generic #48-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Fri Sep 27 14:04:52 UTC 2024 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Architecture:             x86_64
  CPU op-mode(s):         32-bit, 64-bit
  Address sizes:          48 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
  Byte Order:             Little Endian
CPU(s):                   4
  On-line CPU(s) list:    0-3
Vendor ID:                AuthenticAMD
  Model name:             AMD FX(tm)-770K Quad Core Processor
    CPU family:           21
    Model:                48
    Thread(s) per core:   2
    Core(s) per socket:   2
    Socket(s):            1
    Stepping:             1
    Frequency boost:      enabled
    CPU(s) scaling MHz:   43%
    CPU max MHz:          3500.0000
    CPU min MHz:          1400.0000
    BogoMIPS:             6987.18
    Flags:                fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush mmx fxsr sse sse2 ht syscall nx mmxext fxsr_opt pdpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc rep_g
                          ood nopl nonstop_tsc cpuid extd_apicid aperfmperf pni pclmulqdq monitor ssse3 fma cx16 sse4_1 sse4_2 popcnt aes xsave avx f16c lahf_lm cmp_legacy extapic cr8_legacy
                           abm sse4a misalignsse 3dnowprefetch osvw ibs xop skinit wdt lwp fma4 tce nodeid_msr tbm topoext perfctr_core perfctr_nb bpext ptsc cpb hw_pstate ssbd vmmcall fsgsb
                          ase bmi1 xsaveopt arat npt lbrv svm_lock nrip_save tsc_scale vmcb_clean flushbyasid decodeassists pausefilter pfthreshold overflow_recov


Also asked at https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2502322

I am running ubuntu 24.04 LTS, PLEASE check imgur link for system info. its a 10 year old desktop. its a default kernel I didn't changed anything during installation. Kernel version 6.8.0-48 generic.

Its Solved here https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2502322&p=14212445#post14212445
